# Calculator function based on passed in arguments

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I am building a simple calculator as homework. The function takes two numbers (number1, number2) and an operator (+, -, *, /) as argument.

However there are several scenarios:

1. If the operator is missing --> return "wrong data provided"
2. If not, then calculate normally
3. If number 2 is missing --> assume number "0" for + & - calculation and "1" for * & / calculation

**EDIT: scenario 3 should account for only 2 arguments (1 number and 1 operator) passed in. I am aware it is not the correct way to call the function but it is part of the task I try to solve.**

This is what I tried

```
function calc (number1, number2, operator) {
    if (operator == undefined) {
        return "wrong data provided"
    } else {
        if (operator == "+") {
            return number1+number2
        } else if (operator == "-") {
            return number1-number2
        } else if (operator == "*") {
            return number1*number2
        } else if (operator == "/") {
            return number1/number2
        }
    } 

    if (number2 == undefined) {
        if (operator == "+") {
                number2=0;
            return number1+number2
        } else if (operator == "-") {
                number2=0;
            return number1-number2
        } else if (operator == "*") {
            number2=1;
            return number1*number2
        } else if (operator == "/") {
            number2=1;
            return number1/number2
        }
    }  else {
        if (operator == "+") {
            return number1+number2
        } else if (operator == "-") {
            return number1-number2
        } else if (operator == "*") {
            return number1*number2
        } else if (operator == "/") {
            return number1/number2
        }
    } 
}
```

calc(50,"+") leads to "wrong data provided. Why?

Comment: Parameters are in order, meaning `calc(50,"+")` has `number1` as `50`, `number2` as `"+"` and `operator` as `undefined`.

Comment: Where is your `number2` parameter ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, that it should account for only 1 number and 1 parameter being passed.

Comment: Beside how you call the function, you also have the orders of the checks wrong, if `operator` is not `undefined` you'll never check if `number2` is `undefined`. Your function will always return from the first `if...else` statement if `operator` is `undefined` or any of the `+`, `-`, `*` or `/` characters.

Comment: Just as a general thought, if you shall assume 0 for + and - and 1 for * and / if number2 is missing, that's just a complicated way of saying "if number2 is missing, return number 1". Saves you a lot of code and checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
function calc(par1, par2, par3) {
  var number1 = par1;
  var operator;
  var number2;
  if (typeof par2 === 'string') {
    operator = par2;
  } else {
    number2 = par2;
    operator = par3;
  }
  if (typeof operator === "undefined") {
    return "wrong data provided"
  } else {
    if (operator == "+") {
      return number1 + (number2 || 0);
    } else if (operator == "-") {
      return number1 - (number2 || 0);
    } else if (operator == "*") {
      return number1 * (typeof number2 === 'undefined' ? 1 : 0);
    } else if (operator == "/") {
      return number1 / (typeof number2 === 'undefined' ? 1 : 0);
    }
  }
}

console.log(calc(50, '+'));
console.log(calc(50, '*'));
console.log(calc(50, 20, '+'));
console.log(calc(50, undefined, '*'));
console.log(calc(50, 10));
```

Here, I've used `(number2 || 0)` to make the calculation using `number2` or `0` for the `-` and `+` operations when `number2` is `undefined` or 
 `0` and `(typeof number2 === 'undefined' ? 1 : 0)` to make the calculation using `number2` or `1` for the `*` and `/` operations when `number2` is `undefined`.

Comment: Sorry, I am afraid I am not so far as let and const :/

The rest I understaand

Comment: @user2132380 You can replace both of those with `var`. `const` and `let` are just some different ways of declaring variables in the newer versions of JavaScript.

Comment: So I basically say, 

- number 1 will always be par1
- there is a number2 variable
- there is an operator variable 
- if second argument is a string then operator is whatever second argument is 
- in all other cases stick to the default (that is second argument is number 2, and third argument operator)

Later, these expressions (number2 || 0); will make the script choose between number2 if defined and 0 if only two arguments, right?

Comment: Yes, that is mostly right. There is an error in there that I will edit the answer to fix. In case `number2` is `0` and `operator` is `*` or `/`, `number2` will be set to `1`.

Comment: OK, you lost me with this Syntax. I understand you want to avoid divisions (especially) and multiplications with 0 but what does the syntax say?

Comment: Also I think it's only necessary for the division since multiplying leads to 0 which is a perfectly fine result

Comment: @user2132380 That is just a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) which uses the first value after the condition (the part before the `?` character) if the condition is `true` otherwise it uses the second value (the one after the `:` character). So, basically, if `number2` is `undefined`, use `1`, otherwise use `number2`'s value.

Answer (score 1):

**Better code:**

```
function calculate(number1,number2,operator){
if (!number1 || !number2){
    return "Invalid number"
}
if (!['*','-','/','+'].includes(operator)){
    return "Invalid operator"
}
switch(operator){
  case "+":
    return number1 + number2;
  case "/":
    return number1 * number2;
  case "*":
    return number1 * number2;
  case "-":
    return number1 - number2;
 }
}
console.log(calculate(5,6,"+"))
```

Comment: The OP mentioned that `number2` can be `undefined` and in those cases it should be set to `0` or `1` based on the `operator`'s value.

Answer (score 0):

```
calc(50,"+")
```

here you are passing only 2 arguments. so the 3rd paramter is undefined

```
calc(50,,"+")
```

Pass 3 paramters instead

Comment: why don't you pass one more parameter to check whether it should check with 3 parameter or 2 parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your variables has follow

- number1 will come from params
- number2 will be as parameters unless there is an operator instead of a number. if there is an operator, it will be 0 or 1 depends on the operator
- operator will take his value from parameters or from number2

```js
const operators = ["+", "-", "*", "/"];

function calc(number1, n2, op) {

// the part i add
  let number2;
  let operator = op;
  if (operators.includes(n2)) {
      if (n2 == "+" || n2 == "-") {
        number2 = 0;
      } else {
        number2 = 1;
      }
      operator = n2;
    } else {
      number2 = n2;
    }

    if (operator == undefined) {
      return "wrong data provided"
    } else {
      if (operator == "+") {
        return number1 + number2
      } else if (operator == "-") {
        return number1 - number2
      } else if (operator == "*") {
        return number1 * number2
      } else if (operator == "/") {
        return number1 / number2
      }
    }

    if (number2 == undefined) {
      if (operator == "+") {
        number2 = 0;
        return number1 + number2
      } else if (operator == "-") {
        number2 = 0;
        return number1 - number2
      } else if (operator == "*") {
        number2 = 1;
        return number1 * number2
      } else if (operator == "/") {
        number2 = 1;
        return number1 / number2
      }
    } else {
      if (operator == "+") {
        return number1 + number2
      } else if (operator == "-") {
        return number1 - number2
      } else if (operator == "*") {
        return number1 * number2
      } else if (operator == "/") {
        return number1 / number2
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(calc(50, "+"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass the wrong data to function.
In javascript, you need to pass all params.

```
calc(50, "+")
```

you will get an undefined 3rd parameter and all the time will be "wrong data provided"
Try this

```
calc(50, 0, "+")
```

Comment: Updated with an EDIT

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you have to call with correct arguments. `calc(50,0,"+")`. However you can do a hack - common in many libraries.

```js
function calc (number1, number2, operator) {
    operator = operator || number2;
    number2 = (number2 === operator) ? undefined : number2;

    // Rest keep the same
    if (operator == undefined) {
        return "wrong data provided"
    }
```

First step - `operator = operator || number2;` - is to set `operator` into `operator`, but if it is falsy (false, undefined, 0 etc...) it will assign number2.

Second step - `number2 = (number2 === operator) ? undefined : number2;` is to set number2 into undefined if number2 and operator are strictly equals.
If they are not same, assign original value aka number2.

Now you can call `calc(50,"+")` and it will do the same as `calc(50,0,"+")`

**EDIT:** Please note, this will not work now, as first `if` will be false, so it will immediately try to do the math... So you have to change it at least this way:

```js
if (operator == undefined) {
    return "wrong data provided"
} else if (number2 != undefined) {
  ...
```

Comment: From the OP's description it seems that `number2` can be `undefined` when `operator` is not.

Comment: Hmmm ... don't get your EDIT. Do you suggest that the order of IF statements is wrong?

Comment: @user2132380 yes. First `if` shouldn't have `else` part. Because it is the same as the `else` part of last `if`. If you skip that, it will work. However there are better solutions, shorter and more clear.